# How can I run my C# application having SQL database in another machine?

Tags: c#

I am using SQL Express for managing database in windows application programmed in C#.
I am using the connection string `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=caf;Integrated Security=True` but it is not working in another machine. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: This could be caused by a whole lot of things. You connection string looks like it's connecting to a local database. Is the database on the other machine? What error message are you getting back?

Comment: It is like server instance problem.

Comment: Is SQL installed on the other machine as an instance named `SQLEXPRESS`?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the: Server=myServerAddress;

[Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"

Comment: Firewall on the other machine maybe?

Comment: thanku. if I give it my computer name then it  will only work in my machine. Is there any way to get the user name of another machine in which it is to be installed

Comment: You need to set the server parameter in the configuration string to the ip or named pipe in where the SQL instance is running and make sure external connections to that machine are allowed,

Comment: Why would you add 127.0.0.1? You need to add the "external" ip not that localhost one.

Comment: it gives an error. Error 26: error locating server/instance specified.

Comment: Why should I use external IP because it is only working in local server.